# find all possible ways to connect a disconnected undirected graph and calculate shortest path from src to destination for each possibility

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic, graph

In this problem you are given an undirected graph that is disconnected and 2D matrix with distances between each vertices. I'm trying to find all possible ways to make a connected graph from this state then calculate the distance of a shortest path from vertex 0 to vertex 1 for each possible combination.  Vertex 0 is chosen to be a source vertex and all vertices with a path to vertex 0 is considered connected and all vertices without a path to vertex 0 is not connected. I'm trying to use BFS to find all possible paths but optimize using dynamic programming but can't figure out what the subproblem and the data structure should be.

For example given this graph with V = {0,1,2} and adj matrix (first one) and distances between each matrix (2nd one):

```
  0 1 2          0 1 2
0 0 0 0        0 0 3 4
1 0 0 1        1 3 0 1
2 0 1 0        2 4 1 0
```

since vertices 1 and 2 are not connected, if I connect 0 to 1 the length of the shortest path will be 3. If I connect 0 to 2, the shortest path from 0 to 1 will be 4+1. Both cases are equally likely.

What is the subproblem and how should I be solving this problem?

Comment: I don't understand how the two matrices fit together. It seems to me that the top row and left column denote the vertices and don't belong to the matrix. But why are there only three vertices in the matrices? You mention four vertices above. It is not completely clear to me what your optimization target is. First you write that you want all pollibilities for connecting. Then you write you want to optimize. Do you really want all possibilities or only one which meets a criterion best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collapse the connected components into single vertexes of a multigraph (graph where a multiple edges can be connecting two vertexes). Use any backtracking search to enumerate all the spanning trees of the multigraph.

The irreducible complexity of this task is K!, where K is the number of connected components.

Calculate connected components with a transitive closure algorithm.